# Black background on linux mint 19 after login

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have been the whole day with this problem and I don't know what else to do. I have a Linux Mint 19 on an Asus R510J and until yesterday, everything was working fine. But today, when I started the computer and made the login (which looked normal), the desktop looked with black background and no panel, although I could still see the icons and the mouse, and I could actually open that programs (only that because I had no other option on the screen), but I couldn't even open a terminal. Besides, the icons of the windows I could open were incorrect, as they didn't show the 3 icons (close, max, min) at the right top corner).

After digging a little about it, I did the login in Software Rendering mode, and it looked fine, but I can only open Google Chrome, Firefox and the FIle Manager. I can see the panel, and watch the list with all programs, but when I click, they don't open (neither the terminal).

PS: Yesterday, I installed Python 3.7 following this https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how- ... ntu-18-10/ It's the only difference with previous days

What is happening and what can I do to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was a problem with the Python installation.

I finally got it working following this: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=305987&p=1719076